# Secure JWT against XSS with _additional_ cookie?

Tags: security, jwt

My understanding is:

Cookie-based solution can be secure against XSS easily by making the cookie httpOnly. However a cookie-based solution is susceptible to CSRF (if not secured by an additional token).

JWT has an advantage here, because CSRF is not possible by default.
JWT however can be exploited as part of a XSS weakness, because the token must be available to JavaScript. This is considered not-a-big-deal, because XSS is easier understood and easier to protect against.

But: Why not use JWT and also add an httpOnly-cookie (containing a signature of the token) to get the best of both worlds?

When generating the token, the server would also generate a signature from the token and send it back in a cookie. (The token is still send to the client exactly as always.) (The signature must of course be different from the signature contained in the token.)

When the server receives a request it checks if the cookie is also sent and compares its value to a freshly calculated signature of the token.

So: Since this method is not commonly implemented already, there must be something important I have overlooked, right?

(The only issues that comes to my mind is the old problem of cookies and multiple domains / CORS.)

Comment: By setting HttpOnly on the cookie storing the token, the token is sent to your webserver inside of the cookie on each request and the server must automatically read and process it.  A CSRF attack works by making your browser, with it's authentication cookies (in this case a cookie containing the token), send the malicious request.  If your tokens are automatically passed inside a cookie to the webserver without you needing to add them manually to the authentication header, then you are open to CSRF attacks.

Comment: @TrevorWard Please *read* my question. The cookie does *not* contain the token. The cookie only contains an addition signature of the token and any check on the cookie is only *additional* to checking the Token, which must be send normally.

Comment: What if an attacker got his hands on your token through XSS (since it's not http only).  He could then exploit your cookie checking system with a CSRF attack.  While your solution makes it harder to break in to your site, there's still a vulnerability there.